# Boost Hana Compile-Time List Transformation

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, boost-hana

I'm trying to figure out how to transform a list of integer constants at compile time using boost:hana.

I have my list as:

```
constexpr auto vals = hana::to<hana::tuple_tag>(hana::range_c<int, 0, 3>);
```

I want to apply the function:

```
constexpr auto Pow2(int i) { return 1 << i; }
```

However

```
constexpr auto res = hana::transform(list, Pow2);
```

produces a type for res of `hana::tuple<int, int, int>`.  I'm not seeing how to move the argument to the lambda into a template argument for `hana::int_c`

```
// Compiler error: Non-type template argument is not a constant expression
constexpr auto Pow2(int i)
{
    return hana::int_c<1 << i>{};
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ...

```
constexpr auto Pow2(int i) { return 1 << i; }
```

...`i` is a *runtime integer*. It is not a *"compile-time-friendly"* parameter, as its value is not stored as part of its type. You should pass in a `int_` instead:

```
template <int X>
constexpr auto Pow2(hana::int_<X>) { return hana::int_c<1 << X>; }
```

Usage:

```
constexpr auto vals = hana::to<hana::tuple_tag>(hana::range_c<int, 0, 3>);
constexpr auto res = hana::transform(vals, [](auto x){ return Pow2(x); });

static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    std::decay_t<decltype(res)>,
    hana::tuple<hana::int_<1>, hana::int_<2>, hana::int_<4>>
>);
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bS1mSaVDDw9DJl7k)

---

Obviously, you can also do this with a lambda. Additionally, `boost::hana::int_` has an `operator<<` overload that returns an `int_`:

```
hana::transform(vals, [](auto x){ return hana::int_c<1> << x; });
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ghuPHqUe0SzFjr86)

Comment: Thanks.  I was wondering if this was the good approach and it was just my compiler that didn't support the canonical technique.  Swtiching your example to clang 3.9.1

`prog.cc:12:20: error: constexpr variable 'res' must be initialized by a constant expression
    constexpr auto res = hana::transform(vals, [](auto x){ return hana::int_c<1> << x; });`

Is there any way to make it work with clang 3.9.1?

Comment: @user78145: yes, just get rid of the `constexpr` in `constexpr res`

Comment: The reason why that does not work is because lambdas can't be constexpr in C++14, a silly restriction that is lifted in C++17.